# Maintain ration on textarea resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to scale the FONT SIZE of a textarea and maintain its ratio when a browser window is resized?

My requirement: There is an image on the background and on the foreground I'm having a textarea where the user is allowed to add their text. I need to maintain the textarea's position and ratio when the bowser window is resized.

Comment: can you create jsfiddler or jsbin for it.

Comment: You should be able to do this with simple pixels.. On the resize event for the textbox/browser window.. Simply calculate the total width of the browser and resize your textbox to that with what ever ratio you have. Same goes for the font-size.. You would work out the ratio/scale of the font and then apply this as well....fontsize = (textbox.width / 40) as pseudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use jQuery, then the following code will adjust both the size of the textarea and the size of the font based on the resizing of the window.

Before executing the code, make sure that the size of the textarea and the font size are set (i.e. anything that will change the size of those has loaded and executed).

The font size (including unit) is read from CSS, and updated based on changes in the height of the window; the width is ignored. I doubt you were planning on changing the font aspect ratio.

There are optimisations that could be made (only resizing the dimensions that changed; only changing the font when the window height changes), but I'll leave those to you.

Assumptions:

- the initial size of the font is set in CSS
- the textarea the ratio of which you want to maintain has an id 'mytextarea'.

  ```
      function startResizeHandling(){
          var textarea = $('#mytextarea');
          var initialHeight = textarea.height(),
              widthRatio = textarea.width()/$(window).width(),
              heightRatio = initialHeight/$(window).height(),
              cssFontSize = textarea.css('font-size');
          var fontRatio = parseFloat(cssFontSize.match(/^([0-9.]+)/)[1]) / initialHeight,
              fontUnit = cssFontSize.match(/^[0-9.]+([a-z]+)$/i)[1];

          function handleWindowResize() {
              var newWidth = widthRatio * $(window).width(),
                  newHeight = heightRatio * $(window).height();
              textarea.width(newWidth);
              textarea.height(newHeight);
              textarea.css('font-size', fontRatio * newHeight + fontUnit);
          }

          $(window).on('resize', handleWindowResize);
      };
  ```

Edit:

Having re-read the question, it isn't clear to me whether you want to:

- scale the font size of a textarea and maintain the ratio of the *textarea*, or
- scale the font size of a textarea and maintain the ratio of the *font* (i.e. actually distort the font)

This answer addresses the first, not the second.